# Ataque DDOS servidor

Tags: servidor, ddos

Olá,

Tenho um servidor que está sofrendo ataque DOS, eu usei o comando:

```
watch -n1 'attackers'
```

no SSH para ver os ataques. Basicamente tem UM ip que faz umas 380 conexões, e faz o servidor cair em poucos minutos.

Eu bloqueio o IP pelo FireWall, mas passa 30 minutos e o rapaz engraçadinho muda de IP e faz o processo de novo.

Faz 5 dias que isso está acontecendo, e a equipe de suporte da Host não consegue dar um JEITO.

Coloquei os sites do meu servidor na CloudFlare, mas nem assim parou. Me falaram que é um DDOS Layer 7..

A cada vez que entro no suporte, me passam um jeito diferente ou que precisam de tempo para fazer algo lá.

Alguém já passou por isto e quer sugestionar alguma possivel solução? Estou cogitando é mudar de HOST.. Mas se eu conseguir fazer algo, melhor e evita menos transtornos.

Servidor é LINUX.
E a empresa que trabalho é a HostGator.
Dedicado Pro.

Comment: Sim, e existem várias formas de se proteger. Uma delas é configurando o AWS WAF no CloudFront. Isso é uma coisa que também preciso fazer num site aqui....to estudando. Mas tb é possível fazer via aplicação um controle de requisições.

Comment: perdão, pensei que Cloudfare era da Amazon....vc esta num ambiente que nao conheço

Comment: Certo amigo. Obrigado de qualquer forma pela tentativa.

Comment: qual servidor http vc está usando? Apache?

Comment: Sim! É um plano Dedicado Pro da HostGator, inclusive bem carinho para o serviço.. Esperava um suporte melhor pelo preço. Eles atendem bem, mas é que demorar 5 dias para resolver um problema de DDOS que acredito que até um criança de 8 anos aprende e faz é complicado, ainda mais que é na Camada 7, que acredito que seja requisições no servidor que estão deixando a CPU 100% e fazendo cair..

Comment: maneira rápida de resolver, desenvolva um script em shell, que conte a quantidade de IP's da mesma origem fazendo tentativas de acesso, para os ips com grande número de tentativas aplique uma regra de drop com iptables, coloque seu script no crontab para rodar a cada 1 minuto...

Comment: instale e configure o fail2ban que tbm vai te ajudar

Comment: Olá, @ederwander , se precisar eu faço isso também. Vou fazer o que o amigo Karl recomendou, ai eu consigo mensurar o que surtiu efeito, certo? Obrigado também. E pelo visto já vão fechar meu tópico. :(, faz parte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solução também depende da sua versão de Apache e do Linux, vou colocar a solução com o **mod_evasive** do **Apache2**.

Primeiro instale o **mod_evasive**

```
sudo apt-get -y install libapache2-mod-evasive
```

Crie o arquivo de log:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/apache2/evasive
```

De as permissões pro arquivo:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:root /var/log/apache2/evasive
```

Altere o arquivo **/etc/apache2/mods-available/mod-evasive.load**

```
DOSHashTableSize 2048
DOSPageCount 20  # maximum number of requests for the same page
DOSSiteCount 300  # total number of requests for any object by the same client IP on the same listener
DOSPageInterval 1.0 # interval for the page count threshold
DOSSiteInterval 1.0  # interval for the site count threshold
DOSBlockingPeriod 10.0 # time that a client IP will be blocked for
DOSLogDir
```

**DOSPageCount** Irá definir quantos requests o usuário pode fazer para a mesma página

**DOSSiteCount** Irá definir quantos requests um mesmo ip poderá fazer para o site

**DOSPageInterval** e **DOSSiteInterval** é o intervalo de tempo em segundos para esta contagem acima

**DOSBlockingPeriod** é o tempo em que ficará bloqueado em segundos

Reinicie o Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Cuidado que dependendo da métrica que você colocar ele pode barrar usuários humanos.

Comment: Karl, vou pedir para implementar este serviço, e volto aqui para dar um feedback. Obrigado pela resposta. :)

Comment: Vc não tem acesso ao servidor via ssh? Pq dai da pra vc mesmo implementar e nao fica dependendo deles.

Comment: Tentei fazer via SSH, mas deu um aviso: sudo: apt-get: command not found. Acredito que esse tal de "apt-get" não esteja disponivel para uso.

Comment: Digita isso `uname -a` no terminal e veja qual linux vc está usando. Coloca o resultado aqui.

Comment: Linux yyy.xxx.com 2.6.32-696.20.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 26 17:51:45 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux - Só ocultei o servidor ali, to receoso já com esses engraçadinhos atacantes.. rsrs

Comment: Claro! Fez certo...estranho...acho q é um RedHat ele tem q ter algum gerenciador de pacotes, apt-get, yum, rpm

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73968/discussion-between-karl-zillner-and-alexandre-c-caus).